# Radio buttons with action and store

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with 4 radio buttons where I need to take the 2 options selected by the user and send it to a socket, but first, I need to know how to update the options selected using an action and a store

here the code where you can see the buttons

```
class BetBehindModal extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Bet Behind Settings</p>
          <p>When seated player Doubles:</p>
          <form>
            <input type="radio" value="double" name="doubles" /> Always Double my bet <br />
            <input type="radio" value="nodouble" name="doubles" /> Never Double my bet
          <p>When seated player Splits:</p>
            <input type="radio" value="split" name="splits" /> Always Split <br />
            <input type="radio" value="nosplit" name="splits" /> Assign bet to 1st hand
          </form>
          <hr />
          <button className="toggleModalBtn" type="submit" onClick={this._confirm}>Confirm</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BetBehindModal;
```

so, there are 4 options, the user has the right to choose 2 of those 4. I need to send that info to a socket and also to a backend made in Nodejs, but the most important part is, how to work with this with the action and the store?

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be a single for with a submit button? Why do you have two forms?

Comment: "how to work with this with the action and the store" – are you asking how to implement Flux? React by itself doesn't have actions or stores.

Comment: Yes, @Pavlo, I am using Flux. I need to do an action and a store in order to send this data to a DB and a socket

Comment: @Pavlo actually I know how to do an action and a store, but to be more specific, I need to know how to get the values of the buttons selected so I can send that info to the store. I don't know if there is a React way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, you having a hard time trying to update the state of your component based on the radio buttons. As a way to do it, you may add `onChange` handler:

```
class BetBehindModal extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.onDoublesChange = this.onDoublesChange.bind(this);
    this.onSplitsChange = this.onSplitsChange.bind(this);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Bet Behind Settings</p>
          <p>When seated player Doubles:</p>
          <form>
            <input type="radio" value="double" name="doubles" onChange={this.onDoublesChange}/> Always Double my bet <br />
            <input type="radio" value="nodouble" name="doubles" onChange={this.onDoublesChange}/> Never Double my bet
          <p>When seated player Splits:</p>
            <input type="radio" value="split" name="splits" onChange={this.onSplitsChange}/> Always Split <br />
            <input type="radio" value="nosplit" name="splits" onChange={this.onSplitsChange}/> Assign bet to 1st hand
          </form>
          <hr />
          <button className="toggleModalBtn" type="submit" onClick={this._confirm}>Confirm</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onDoublesChange({ target }) {
    if (target.checked) this.setState({ doubles: target.value });
  }

  onSplitsChange({ target }) {
    if (target.checked) this.setState({ splits: target.value });
  }
}

export default BetBehindModal;
```

Comment: is there a way to send that state to the store ?